# Adding Gradle tasks to multiple groups

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to add a single Gradle task to multiple groups?

Something along this line:

```
jar.group = ['build', 'archives']
```

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. A task can only be assigned to one group. [The setter method for the property also just takes a String.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#setGroup(java.lang.String))